# Arcpy code repetition provides slight differences in the outputs

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, excel

I made a python script that uses arcpy to buffer some network areas, intersect them with another shapefile, and from this output make some calculations that are saved to an Excel spreadsheet.

I run this code two times, and then used Excel plug-in "Inquire" to compare the two spreadsheet, in order to verify the final results were actually the same. What I noticed is that, on a large amount of cells (13336 x 3), approximatelly 6000 are slightly different. For example, these are two my outputs from the spreadsheets:

`78.08377792455002` and `78.083778014277357`

As you can see, the error is remarkably small (approximatelly 1E-7%) but still, it seems weird to me to have these differences, also because I think other codes, e.g. Matlab, have a higher precision (if I am not wrong, Matlab precision is for relavite errors of 1E-11).

Where does this difference come from? Is it just a computational error or is it due to some mistakes of mine in the way I used ArcGIS or Python?

Comment: Without seeing your code I would guess that the difference comes from mixing float and double data types in your calculations somewhere. Unless you really need that many decimal places I would consider setting the precision and scale of the fields you are working with or rounding the values that are output to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Another area that might cause slight differences is the use of your Spatial Reference System. If your files are not in the same projected coordinate system, or are geographic, you might be getting some errors that way.